# TextInput setFocus not working in flash builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6. and working for a **flex project** in which i want to setFocus on textInput after the intitialize is complete. I am using the code `myTextInput.setFocus()`;
this is working fine cursor are blinking but not Highlighting the TextInput for focusing the TextInput. My All code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="init();">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void{
                myTextInput.setFocus();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Panel x="54" y="23" width="250" height="200">
        <s:TextInput x="98" y="42"/>
        <s:TextInput id="myTextInput" x="98" y="12"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Working fine here. Blue border around the top textinput. Changed the projects skin settings ?

Comment: could be browser specific issue? are you using IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index-template:

> ```
> function setFocus(){
>   window.document.getElementById("APPNAME").focus();
>   $('#myTextInput').focus();
>   $('#myTextInput').focusEnables=true;
> } 
>   </script>  </div>
> ```

Application:

> ```
> private function init():void{
>   if (ExternalInterface.available) {
>       ExternalInterface.call('setFocus');
>   } 
> }
> ```